# NameError: name 'x_train' is not defined

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, machine-learning, scikit-learn

i'm new to this but can anyone tell me what's wrong it? I'm actually trying to do a predictive analysis(linear regression graph) based on the data i have in the excel . However , my graph isn't plotted out and i also faced this error.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy
from sklearn import linear_model
df = pd.read_csv("C:\MongoDB\MongoData.csv") 

x_train = np.array(x_train).reshape(len(x_train), -1)
x_train.shape
y_train= [1,2,3,4,5]
x_test = x_test.reshape(-1, 1)
x_test.shape

linear = linear_model.LinearRegression()

linear.fit(x_train, y_train)
linear.score(x_train, y_train)

print('Coefficient: \n', linear.coef_)
print('Intercept: \n', linear.intercept_)

predicted= linear.predict(x_test)
```

Comment: Obviously, here `x_train = np.array(x_train).reshape(len(x_train), -1)` you're trying to use `x_train` which is not declared yet in `x_train` assignment. It is not allowed

Comment: Missing declaration of x_train before using it as paramam in:
`x_train = np.array(x_train).reshape(len(x_train), -1)`

Comment: you missed a line between line six and seven, that splits df into x_train and x_test. something like `x_train, x_test = ...`

Answer (score 6):

You make use of the variable `x_train` twice before you ever define it. You need to define it first, then use it.

```
  x_train = np.array(x_train).reshape(len(x_train), -1)
# ^^^^^^^            ^^^^^^^              ^^^^^^^
#    |                  |                    |
#    |    +------------------------------------------------+
#    |    | You use x_train twice before it's ever defined |
#    |    +------------------------------------------------+
#  +------------------------------------------+
#  | Your first definition of x_train is here |
#  +------------------------------------------+
```